# Partial application using class method

Tags: this, bind, es6-class

Say I have the following:

```js
class A {
  _a = 3

  method(arg) {
    return arg + this._a;
  }
}
```

and I create a partial application as such:

```js
const part = function (fn) {
  return function (arg) {
    return fn(arg);
  }
}
```

which I apply as follows:

```js
const a = new A();
const newFn = part(a.method, 5);
```

It throws an error that `this is undefined`. So I understand that I can bind the function:

```js
const newFn = part(a.method.bind(a), 5);
```

And then it'll work, but this sucks! Is there a way to do this without having to pass context? That'd include not having to pass it as a parameter (e.g., `part(a, a.method, 5);`, with some refactoring using `bind`)

Note that in reality, I'm using a class from a library, so unfortunately I can't refactor it

---

Just to expand upon the comment, that'd look something like (no destructuring, as destructuring the methods also causes context problems:

```js
const part = function (ctx) {
  return function (fn) {
    return function (arg) {
      return fn.bind(ctx, arg);
    }
  }
}

const a = new A();
const partA = part(a);

// Now for all methods with the class A context I can do
const newFn = partA(a.method, 5);
```

Comment: So far, I'm leaning towards destructuring the methods of `a`, and then creating another layer within the partial application using `a` as an argument with `bind`. Would love to avoid that if possible!

Comment: Turns out you can't even do the destructuring of methods on a class. :(